# How to clone Mongo DB schema from URI (clone only schema, no data)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, parse-platform

TL;DR: a nutshell: I want to copy all classes with their columns (column names and type), but without data, from a URI

uri example: `mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]`

I'm looking for a method/library/suggestion to **clone a Mongo db Schema from a Mongo URI**. I do not have access to the IU (in order to export schema).

I'm using a Parse Server app, so I can manipulate the data and schema, but it's required to be able to clone the schema recurrently with a cronjob. (no manual copies then).

I found a couple of libraries that can be used to clone databases, or create a JSON file from a schema (plane mongo or using mongoose), **but these alternatives does not take a URI**, but uses a schema instanced by my own.

I hope a hand, suggestion, anything where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by "clone Schema from URI" can you explain in layman's terms what you are trying to achieve

Comment: it is an interesting request indeed to clone schema from schema-less database system ...

Comment: @R2D2 well, according to mongo db docs:
"A schema is a JSON object that defines the the structure and contents of your data." (a little bit passive aggressive comment of yours hahah)

Comment: @semperlabs in a nutshell: i want to copy all classes with their columns (column names and type), but without data, from a URI (example: mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]])

Comment: Have you tried with this https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/reference/mongodrdl/#mongodrdl

Comment: @semperlabs i think this could be the solution!! thank you! i'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to achieve this:

1. Using mongodb-compass and proceed with the UI assistant.
2. Using mongodrdl:
   https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/reference/mongodrdl/
   (link provided by @semperlabs)